# How to validate integer input in my form page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, jsp

I m creating from page for customer so everything works well until i wanted to force the user to enter a number in the field "free passes" i got error

i've tried to creat a field with Integer type named freePasses in the Customer class then generate the getter and setters for it, i've alslo modify my .properties file

[image: works fine]

[image: Error]

Customer.java

```
@Min(value = 0 , message="the value must be equal or greater than 0")
    @Max(value = 10, message = "the value must be equal or less than 10")
    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    private Integer freePasses;

public Integer getFreePasses() {
        return freePasses;
    }



    public void setFreePasses(Integer freePasses) {
        this.freePasses = freePasses;
    }
```

applocation.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
typeMismatch.customer.freePasses = invalid Number
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property freePasses; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "44xxxx"

Comment: An `input` field can be of type `number`. It doesn't have to be `text`.

Comment: i m using the spring mvc so the jsp file was
<form:input path="freePasses"/> i can't see how to define type in it ?

Comment: I don't know spring, but I would guess that you add the attribute `type="number"`

Comment: well there is no type ="" in the spring mvc <form:input...

Comment: Did you try to add @Pattern to freePasses and inside pattern enter the regex for numbers only ?

Comment: yes yes didn't work for Integert type i guess i should modify it for String so i can work with regex

Comment: Well I remember one of my projects and for numbers we used String field and @NumberFormat annotation

Comment: i ll try to create my own validator so

Comment: The problem is that textbox values will always be of type String unless you convert the string value to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<form:input type=?number? path="date" />`  will work.

Comment: i use spring mvc mate

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-form-text-field Look at this link then. It is Spring MVC. Sorry if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

create file:  src/resources/messages.properties 
and write this line:

```
typeMismatch.customer.freePasses= Invalid number
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : Add below code in your spring configuration xml file

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="resources/messages"></property>
</bean>
```

Solution 2 : change in your input element

**<form:input type="number" path="freePasses" />** this worked for me try this

Answer (score 0):

In messages.properties file, after the error type, you must to specify the modell **attribute** (which is in your CustomerController) name, not the class name. So typeMismatch.***attribute name***.freePasses= Invalid number.